# Angular Router Subscribe - events.subscribe => url is not a property?

Tags: angular, router

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {  Route, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],

})

 constructor(router: Router)
 {
    router.events.subscribe(e => { 
      sessionStorage.setItem('redirectAuthPreviousRouteUrl',e.url);
    });
}
```

Looking for some help on addressing the below compiler error for the above code. The property does exist as part of the angular router event and i'm able to manipulate it and use it, but not compile it when trying to build.

```
src/app/app.component.ts(18,105): 
error TS2339: Property 'url' does not exist on type 'Event'.
```

What is the proper way for setting a value I've subscribed to when it thinks the property does not exist, or may not exist in certain instances?

I am using Angular 6

Comment: Could you provide the entire component code? This "event" should be instance of RouterEvent (described here https://angular.io/api/router/RouterEvent) not 'Event'. Which kind of object is this `router`?

Comment: @ChristianBenseler According to the docs at https://angular.io/api/router/Router#properties the `events` property is an `Observable<Event>`

Comment: How are you getting this 'router'? Via dependency injection? Provide the app.component.ts code. Technically what you did should work, if you are following this here https://angular.io/api/router/RouterEvent because event emited will be instance of RouterEvent

Comment: @ChristianBenseler I've posted the full code, it should be an injection into the component if my understanding is correct.

Comment: Did you try to filter the events, and return only those that are instance of a RouterEvent (the kind that has url property), as shown in the link I have provided? `.filter(e => e instanceof RouterEvent).subscribe()`

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that the `Event` interface does not have a `url` property, although many of the implementing classes to.

If you know what type of `Event` you're interested in, you can do something like:

```
router.events.subscribe(e => { 
  if (e instanceof ResolveStart)
    sessionStorage.setItem('redirectAuthPreviousRouteUrl', e.url);
});
```

Which will prevent the compilation error, but also ensure that event is the type you're expecting (thereby preventing you from accidentally setting `redirectAuthPreviousRouteUrl` to undefined)

Comment: Where do I import resolveStart from, as it throws a "cannot find ResolveStart" error

Comment: @Troyd from '@angular/router' (although at a guess you're probably more interested in the `NavigationEnd` event from the same module)